# How to copy a file from ftp server to local directory using sftp and spring boot,Java

Tags: spring-boot, sftp

I have codes for Inbound and Outbound channel adapter over SFTP. I want to call those method via spring boot scheduler not using polling. Looking for example how to call resultFileHandler() method

```
public class SftpConfig {
    @Value("${nodephone.directory.sftp.host}")
    private String sftpHost;
    @Value("${nodephone.directory.sftp.port}")
    private int sftpPort;
    @Value("${nodephone.directory.sftp.user}")
    private String sftpUser;
    @Value("${nodephone.directory.sftp.password}")
    private String sftpPasword;
    @Value("${nodephone.directory.sftp.remote.directory.download}")
    private String sftpRemoteDirectoryDownload;
    @Value("${nodephone.directory.sftp.remote.directory.upload}")
    private String sftpRemoteDirectoryUpload;
    @Value("${nodephone.directory.sftp.remote.directory.filter}")
    private String sftpRemoteDirectoryFilter;
    @Value("${nodephone.directory.sftp.remote.directory.localDirectory}")
    private String sftpLocalDirectory;

    // private FtpOrderRequestHandler handler;

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory<LsEntry> sftpSessionFactory() {
        DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(true);
        factory.setHost(sftpHost);
        factory.setPort(sftpPort);
        factory.setUser(sftpUser);
        factory.setPassword(sftpPasword);
        factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
        return new CachingSessionFactory<LsEntry>(factory);
    }

    @Bean
    public SftpInboundFileSynchronizer sftpInboundFileSynchronizer() {
        SftpInboundFileSynchronizer fileSynchronizer = new SftpInboundFileSynchronizer(sftpSessionFactory());
        fileSynchronizer.setDeleteRemoteFiles(true);
        fileSynchronizer.setRemoteDirectory(sftpRemoteDirectoryDownload);
        fileSynchronizer.setFilter(new SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter(sftpRemoteDirectoryFilter));
        return fileSynchronizer;
    }

    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "fromSftpChannel", poller = @Poller(cron = "0/5 * * * * *"))
    public MessageSource<File> sftpMessageSource() {
        SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource source = new SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(
                sftpInboundFileSynchronizer());
        source.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
        source.setLocalFilter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<File>());
        source.setLocalDirectory(new File("/local"));
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "fromSftpChannel")
    public MessageHandler resultFileHandler() {
        return new MessageHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {

                System.out.println("********************** " + message.getPayload());

            }
        };
    }
```

I have tested with Configuration annotation and it reads the file from the server, but I want to run this from Cron instead of polling, how do I call the method resultFileHandler()

Comment: You have specified the cron, right?

Comment: This code polls the file every 5 minute and the closes the session. (If not you can search on ensuring that connection is closed).

If you wish to not use the Poller, you'll have to write this logic, probably, inside a tasklet and execute that tasklet on cron.

Comment: since being quite new in spring boot, I just dont know how to call the functions manually. For example, which method to call for file download instead of putting everything under @congifuration. This code works fine by itself but I just want to control the download mechanism from my class

Answer (score 0):

I've never done this using Spring Integration in any production code although I did something like below, to download files from remote servers using sftp/ftp.

I'm only using the SftpOutboundGateway (*there could be better ways*), to call the **"mget"** method and fetch the payload (file).

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "sftp")
@Setter
@Getter
@EnableIntegration
public class RemoteFileConfiguration {

  private String clients;
  private String hosts;
  private int ports;
  private String users;
  private String passwords;


  @Bean(name = "clientSessionFactory")
  public SessionFactory<LsEntry> clientSessionFactory() {
    DefaultSftpSessionFactory sf = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory();
    sf.setHost(hosts);
    sf.setPort(ports);
    sf.setUser(users);
    sf.setPassword(passwords);
    sf.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
    return new CachingSessionFactory<>(sf);
  }

  @Bean
  @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sftpChannel")
  public MessageHandler clientMessageHandler() {

    SftpOutboundGateway sftpOutboundGateway = new SftpOutboundGateway(
        clientSessionFactory(), "mget", "payload");
    sftpOutboundGateway.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
    sftpOutboundGateway.setLocalDirectory(new File("/users/localPath/client/INPUT/"));
    sftpOutboundGateway.setFileExistsMode(FileExistsMode.REPLACE_IF_MODIFIED);
    sftpOutboundGateway.setFilter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<>());
    return sftpOutboundGateway;
  }

}
```

```
@MessagingGateway
public interface SFTPGateway {

  @Gateway(requestChannel = "sftpChannel")
  List<File> get(String dir);

}
```

To ensure we use cron to execute this, I have used a Tasklet which is executed by Spring Batch, when I need it to be using a cron expression.

```
@Slf4j
@Getter
@Setter
public class RemoteFileInboundTasklet implements Tasklet {

  private RemoteFileTemplate remoteFileTemplate;
  private String remoteClientDir;
  private String clientName;

  private SFTPGateway sftpGateway;

  @Override
  public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution stepContribution, ChunkContext chunkContext)
      throws Exception {

    List<File> files = sftpGateway.get(remoteClientDir);

    if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(files)) {
      log.warn("No file was downloaded for client {}.", clientName);
      return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }

    log.info("Total file: {}", files.size());
    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
  }

}
```

**NOTE:** If you don't want to use Batch's Tasklet, you can use your `@Component` class and inject the Gateway to call "get" method.

```
@Autowired
private SFTPGateway sftpGateway;
```

Comment: I have seen your remofileconfiguration class under @Configuration, doesn't it downloads everything before you even call the method. And also , who implements SFTPGateway? sorry I am quite novice in this

Comment: No it won't download anything, but just ensure connections are made in the factory.
When you call ```sftpGateway.get```, then the method ```mget``` of SftpOutboundGateway is triggered on the channel ```sftpChannel```.

Comment: I don't know what I am doing wrong, it downloads all the file during startup of an application